# Blank screen in android preview

Tags: java, android, preview

So I have a problem with android studio. Mine "preview" is just a blank screen without content,that i actually added. When i run it on avd,i can see this button,and text view,unfortunetly the preview screen is still blank. I don't have any extra libraries,i reinstaled android studio couple of times and just created like ten new project - every case is ending same.

How it's look actually - https://i.stack.imgur.com/zScke.jpg

Comment: What does the event log say?

Comment: You see that red info icon to the right corner of the preview section ? click that info button and there should be an option to refresh the preview. Hopefully that would resolve your problem

Comment: that won't help. I just have some Render problem that says Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error. @AguThadeus not much. 6/13/2018
9:20 PM Gradle sync started

9:20 PM Project setup started

9:20 PM Gradle sync finished in 2s 518ms (from cached state)

Comment: Please share your gradle app file

Comment: You may be using a buggy version of support libraries which leads to this problem, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44449275/failed-to-load-appcompat-actionbar-with-unknown-error-in-android-studio) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47067706/failed-to-load-appcompat-actionbar-with-unknown-error-android-studio-3-0/47067754#47067754) as well, might be helpful

Answer (score 2):

That may be a rendering problem. So you may try to change the app theme.
Click on **App Theme** and select **Holo Light** then click **Ok**.
Hope this would help you.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Update the build.gradle file so the "compileSdkVersion" and "targetSdkVersion" matches the version you are running your emulator.

**For example**

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
targetSdkVersion 26
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.2"
compile "com.android.support:design:26.0.2
```

Also try some of the options mentioned here [instead of preview, Android Studio showing only black screen with 'android...ActionBarOverlayLayout' written on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47049177/instead-of-preview-android-studio-showing-only-black-screen-with-android-act).
Like Goto: src -> main -> res -> style.xml and add Base. to the style tag parent attribute.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
...
</style>
```