# Android Studio cannot render lay-out

Tags: android

The lay-out of this simple Android Studio project ("Hello World") is not rendering, neither in "Design" or "Blueprint" view. At the bottom of the screenshot you see the error message. Can anyone solve this problem? [image]

Comment: Look the "Exception Details" downthere, you using something that doesnt exists

Comment: Maybe try Invalidate Caches/Restart to be sure...

Comment: I had the same issue some days ago. 

On my styles.xml, my AppTheme parent was "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar". I changed it to "Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" and the preview started working. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34016201/2240976)

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50844399/blank-screen-in-android-preview/50845480#50845480

Comment: Try to refresh the layout or change the App theme. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50844399/blank-screen-in-android-preview/50845480#50845480

Comment: Adding "Base" as suggested did the job! Thx!

Answer (score 0):

This same problem bugged me for awhile but stack overflow has the same question answered it just depends on how you search it.

By searching the "Failed to load AppCompat…" you get a great answer in the following thread.

[Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44449275/failed-to-load-appcompat-actionbar-with-unknown-error-in-android-studio)

Basically Go To **res/values/styles.xml** then change the...

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

to

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

*Notice the "Base." in front of Theme.