# How to display elements in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I've been trying to run a simple example project in Android Studio.
The problem is that every single element I create in the project does not appear in the design. I tried to fix the constraint but the result is the same.
[This is the very simple empty activity from the SDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trpj8.png).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

package com.app.aleatorio.aleatorio;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That May be a Rendering problem. You can Solve this by changing the app theme.

Click on **App Theme** and select **Holo Ligh**t then click **OK**.

Check this for more info [Blank screen in android preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50844399/blank-screen-in-android-preview/50845480#50845480)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at your target sdk, minimum sdk version and compile sdk version. They should match or at least be compatible. Here is a short excerpt:

http://www.dummies.com/web-design-development/mobile-apps/the-compile-sdk-minimum-sdk-and-target-sdk-versions/