# Recyclerview preview showing grey screen with android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView in center

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

I am trying to add Recyclerview to my activity layout but the layout preview shows me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvGrp.jpg). I went through all possible answers which i could find out and tried doing things like

1. changing app theme to holo.light
2. adding `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">` to `res>styles.xml`
3. went through all possible relating questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47049177/instead-of-preview-android-studio-showing-only-black-screen-with-android-act) and [this as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45105932/android-studio-3-constraint-layout-editor-issue) and made changes accordingly in my code.

My `build.gradle` file is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.test"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-alpha3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'

}
```

The same problem occurs when i am trying to use coordinate layout as well in my activity. I am using android studio 3.1.3 and my device that m targeting is of oreo version.

I am not able to figure out whats the problem. Kindly help me out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51591251/android-studio-textview-not-showing-in-design-view-layout/51591502#51591502

Comment: Downgrade your project to SDK 27 and check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.1'
targetSdkVersion 27
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: this did work for me.... but had to change all dependencies as well... just a doubt I had... Will changing targetSdkVersion to 27 effect the application if it is installed on oreo based android phone?? @Faysal

Answer (score 1):

Try doing '**Invalidate Cache / Restart**' in 'File' in Android Studio.

If this doesn't work then try the following:

Add this to your **build.gradle** (project) file :

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried doing what you said but it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this 
com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:20.0.+
or remove alpha and try it

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try changing your sdk version and using an older version of recyclerview (probably version 27) and other libraries you used to see if it works.